# Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function" in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I use the laravel 5.6 and vue js is 2.5 and sweetalert2 8.14.0 and I need alert when i submit the form :

```js
//app.js
import swal from 'sweetalert2'
  window.swal =  swal;
const toast =  swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: 'top-end',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 3000
});
window.toast =  toast;
```

// in vue

```js
createUser()
{
  this.$Progress.start();
  this.form.post('api/user');
  toast({
    type: 'success',
    title: 'User Created in successfully'
  })
  this.$Progress.finish();
  },
},
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML and more of the file that has `createUser()` in it?

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like you're just calling SweetAlert incorrectly.

So rather than this:

```js
toast({
  type: 'success',
  title: 'User Created in successfully'
})
```

it should be:

```js
toast.fire({
  type: 'success',
  title: 'User Created in successfully'
})
```

Alternatively if you want to use `toast` as a function you could define it as:

```js
window.toast = function (...args) {
  return toast.fire(...args);
};
```